# How to make an element ignore a particular style sheet

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make an element ignore a particular stylesheet?

For example:

```
<div class="hola"></div>
```

styles.css:

```
.hola {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

bootstrap.css:

```
div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I want my div `.hola` to only listen to styles.css.

I thought maybe this can be down with jQuery or something like that.

Comment: Not possible to my knowledge. You will simply have to override styles that you don't want to apply. Here's a link on precedence if you need a reference on how to do that. http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Your only real options are: make your `div.hola` a web component (kinda complex but to learn more: http://webcomponents.org/), put `div.hola` in an iframe (that's probably silly in your use case), or override all of bootstraps css (probably the best option).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to ignore certain css already defined for a specific class or tag, is to override it for a more specific case. CSS will pick the value for a certain style property (e.g. padding or margin) that is most specific, e.g. :

```
.big-font {
    font-size:16px;
    color: black;
}
.big-font .bit-smallerthough {
    font-size:15px;
}
```

All text within a div with class 'big-font' will have its font-size as 16px, except for the texts  within a div with class 'bit-smallerthough' that lives within the class with 'big-font'. Any other div with class 'bit-smallerthough' outside the 'big-font' div will not be affected by the css.

Another way to override other html is to use the '!important' keyword, which tells the browser to ignore all other style values not tagged with the '!important' keyword. So you could override:

```
.divclass .morespecific .evenspecificerer {
    color:blue;
}
```

with

```
.evenspecificerer {
    color:black !important;
}
```

### However

Having a lot of nested css trees (i.e. evenspecificer = 3 levels nested) will have you ending up with very complex css structures, and is a typical bad code smell. Same goes for stylesheets using the '!important' keyword, using this generally means that you made earlier mistakes creating your css, and should tell you you need to rethink your stylesheets.

### Instead

What is the best option: Define css for classes that make sense. This means that you should probably not define padding or margin for the div element, because you will end up constantly overriding these properties. Instead define a class called 'padding-top-10', having the sole property: padding: 10px;. This allows you to create a very generic stylesheet with no difficult structure with a lot of nesting or nasty '!important' usage.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a reset css that is more specific than the bootstrap rules and which can override them. For instance:

```
div.reset {
    ....default rules for a div
}
```

And your div should look like this

```
  <div class="reset">....</div>
```

Yahoo have some css resources used for this purpose http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

Answer (score 0):

Have your `styles.css` attach after your `bootstrap.css`. This will still apply bootstrap, but will be overwritten by `styles.css`.

you can also use !important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations.

Or grab that DOM Element through JQuery or Javascript to manipulate the style, however this methods is also an override. I haven't see a way to make stop listening to a certain style sheet.

read more about !important: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: bootstrap.css will not be overriden by styles.css just like that. Only when two declarations are totally equal in nesting level will the browser use the order of import to tie break. Therefor you should not rely on the order of attachment as declarations often change.